# What do each the columns from "powercfg /srumutil" mean?

Tags: windows

From the docs: `powercfg /srumutil` "Enumerates the entire Energy Estimation data from the System Resource Usage Monitor (SRUM) in an XML or CSV file."[0]

The column names in the output csv aren't descriptive and I can't find docs to describe what each column means.

What do each of the columns in that csv mean?

[0] https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/design/device-experiences/powercfg-command-line-options#srumutil

Comment: I believe this post would be a better fit at [superuser.com](https://superuser.com). There is literally over 1000 questions about this tool. Also as it stays the post is a bit too broad. Is there a particular column that causes confusion? Check out [this post](https://superuser.com/a/1113194/128116) and a [video linked therein](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/shows/defrag-tools/157-energy-estimation-engine-e3).